# PostgreSQL query for an aggregate count of distinct elements within an array

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, prisma

I'd like to count the total number of occurrences of each unique tag in an array of strings across multiple rows and do it all as part of a PostgreSQL query.

I'm using Prisma, but I suspect if it is possible, I would have to do this via `$queryRaw`.

In my `schema.prisma`, `allTags` is set up as an array of strings:

```
  allTags                 String[]
```

This then got turned into a `_text` in the database schema, and the underscore seems to mean it's an array there:

```
    "allTags" _text,
```

So assuming data like this:

```
allTags
------------------------------
{JavaScript, Vue.js}
{JavaScript, Node}
{TypeScript, JavaScript, Node}
```

...the output should look something like this:

```
count + tag
------------------
3     | JavaScript
2     | Node
1     | Vue.js
1     | TypeScript
```

My hunch is that I might need to use a subquery here somehow (I've seen mention of `LATERAL`), but I can't quite piece it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a lateral join to an unnesting of the array.

```
select count(*) as "count", tag
from your_table t
cross join lateral unnest(allTags) as tags(tag)
group by tag
order by 1 desc;
```

| count | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | JavaScript |
| 2 | Node |
| 1 | Vue.js |
| 1 | TypeScript |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5363fb37d987afa2615b8c2ad8b58ca8)*

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for and works. Thanks!